# Trigonometry - word problem - functions cosθ = adjacent/hypotenuse

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I'm not sure what trigonometric equation I should use for this problem:

At a certain instant, a ship was 5km south of a lighthouse. The ship was travelling westward and after 30 minutes it's bearing was S 53 degrees W. What was the speed of the ship per hour?

I used: cosθ = adjacent/hypotenuse

= (cos53) hypotenuse = adjacent

= hypotenuse = adjacent/cos53 = 5km/0.60 = 8.33km/0.5hr

Speed = distance/time = 8.33km/0.5 hr = 16.66km/hr

Is this correct. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I believe if the bearing from the lighthouse was S 53 degrees W, then the reference angle you would deal with would be 37.  Also, i think you need to be dealing with tan().  You don't care what the distance from the lighthouse is, you need to find the distance traveled West (which represents the adjacent part of the trig ratio), and you know the opposite part of the ratio is 5km.

Comment: Is the equation tan53= 5km/x = 3.77 km/0.5hr then, d/t=3.77/0.5 =7.54km/hr

Comment: @Jeansilvy could you post a diagram?

Comment: It doesn't have any diagram, I had to sketch one myself.. and i don't know how to post it..